# How to query a range of columns MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MYSQL and I'd like to start querying after the first 5 columns and every column from then on.

Is there a way I could something like

```
 select * from table where column 5 begins
```

Also I know that at the 5th column the headers are numbers. So it could also be something like

```
Select * from table where headers=[0-9]
```

Comment: Only by specifying the columns desired explicitly, instead of using `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do

```
SELECT column5, column6, column7 FROM table  -- up to the column you want to stop
```